# Button control style changes the background when IsPress=True, but it never changes back to the original color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

I have an application default button style defined in a XAML resource dictionary. The `ControlTemplate` contains a trigger for `IsPressed="True"`, which changes the button background when the button is pressed.

However, after the button is pressed and released, the background set during the `IsPressed="True"`, the background color never changes back to the original background color.

This is in VS 2019 and .NET core v3.1.

The button xaml is:

```
<Button x:Name="btnHelp" Width="50" Height="25" Content="_Help" Click="btnHelp_Click"  BorderBrush="AliceBlue" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Here is the button style definition in my resource dictionary:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource BaseBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBorderThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="outerborder"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    ClipToBounds="True"
                    CornerRadius="{DynamicResource ButtonCornerRadius}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
                            Name="glow"
                            Margin="{DynamicResource GlowBorderMargin}"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ButtonGlowBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{DynamicResource GlowBorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{DynamicResource ButtonCornerRadius}"
                            Effect="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverGlowEffect}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="content"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuHoverBrush}" />
                        <!--<Setter TargetName="glow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />-->
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundPressedBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DarkerSelectedBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="glow" Property="Effect" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonPressedGlowEffect}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="glow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuHoverBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="outerborder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Better try to use StaticResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the line below in the `IsFocused` trigger. When you click the `Button`, it gets focused, so the trigger will set the `Background` of the button. If you move the focus to another control, e.g. by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the background will change back to normal. Since you use the same background for the *Pressed* and the *Focused* state, it *appears* to be stuck in *Pressed* state, but is *Focused*.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuHoverBrush}" />
```

Remove the line from the trigger and your button will work as expected.

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource SelectedBrush}" />
</Trigger>
```

Comment: This does work for tabbing between buttons, but does not work when pressing a button, mouse leaves the button. The button stays in the pressed background color state and my IsMouseOver trigger no longer works.

Comment: @JeffH I tested this and just leaving out this one setter works for me, the mouse over color, the pressed color and everything else (except for the focused background which was the problem). So either you are talking about a different issue or the code that you posted is not the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't removed the IsFocused trigger because I need it, but I did remove it and everything else works. thanks! Now I need to figure out what to do for the IsFocused.